# Need to solve a ODE using any approximation technique. But, this eqution tends to infinty.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have an ODE equation to solve the velocity of the droplet, the equation reads:

$$ \rho_w u_d \frac{du_d}{dz} =( \rho_w- \rho_a)g-0.75c_d\rho_a\frac{(u_d-u_a)^2}{d_d} $$

I tried solving the equation considering it as an Initial value problem, I found no success as the equation reaches infinity.

$\rho_w$ =1000
$c_d$ =0.44
g= 9.81
$\rho_a$ = 1.25
$u_a$ = 4.55 
intial condtion $u_d$ = 0  at z = 0 
Need to find the variation along the $u_d$ along the height from Z= 0  till Z=4

Comment: I think you are describing a problem where $u_d$ is the unknown function of $z$.  You use $d_d$ in the (nonlinear) differential equation without assigning a value.  The remark "I found no success as the equation reaches infinity" requires clarification.  Finally the request "Need to find the variation along the $u_d$ along the height from $Z=0$ till $Z=4$" is unclear.  Perhaps you simply mean you want to find a numerical solution for $u_d(z)$ on the interval $z\in [0,4]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \rho_w u_d \frac{du_d}{dz} =( \rho_w- \rho_a)g-0.75c_d\rho_a\frac{(u_d-u_a)^2}{d_d} $$A key point in solving an equation is to write it on a standard form where is is easy to distinguish the unknown from the parameters.

In order to make clear this fishy equation, change the notations :

$u_d=y(z)\quad$ unknown function that you are looking for.

$\frac{( \rho_w- \rho_a)g}{\rho_w}=a\quad$ constant.

$\frac{0.75c_d\rho_a}{d_d \rho_w}=b\quad$ constant.

$u_a=c\quad$ constant.
$$y\frac{dy}{dz}=a-b(y-c)^2$$
If you have done so, you would have recognize easily that the equation is a separable ODE which the way to solve is well known.

$$z=\int \frac{y\:dy}{a-b(y-c)^2}$$
Integrating gives the function $z(y)$ on closed form.

Then, one observe that inverting for $y(z)$ is not possible with standard functions. Thus you need numerical calculus to continue. Alternatively, solve directly the original ODE thanks to numerical calculus, which is the common way in practice.